# How to check if a date is a holiday

Tags: javascript, json, date

I have this situation, a form where the user sets the date and a number of days so I can calculate a dead line date via javascript methods. I found an api that return json objects with the holidays in my city. the problem is, when I call my method passing a date that I know that is a holiday and it is present in the json object, the method returns false. If I copy and paste the method line by line on chrome's dev tool, it return true. what am I missing?

**OBS:** the date format used in my country is dd/mm/YYYY, that's why I use some date formatting and to compare with the dates returned in the json objects.

```
function verifyHoliday(date){
  var url = "https://api.calendario.com.br/?json=true&ano=2018&estado=SP&cidade=MOGI_GUACU&token=ZGdvLmRpZWdvY2FydmFsaG9AZ21haWwuY29tJmhhc2g9MTYzMjcxMDY3";
  var day = (date.getDate() < 10) ? "0"+date.getDate() : date.getDate();
  var dateString = day + "/" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + date.getFullYear();

  //====================================================
  var holiday = false;
  var holidays = [];
  $.getJSON(url, function(data){
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
      var obj = {day: data[i].date, name: data[i].name};
      holidays[i] = obj;
    }
  });

  for(var i = 0; i < holidays.length; i++){
    if(holidays[i].day == dateString){
        holiday = true;
        break;
    }
  }
  return feriado;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: $.getJSON is asynchronous, meaning the holidays array is filled *after* the code that iterates it is executed. See duplicate question, this is a very common issue

Comment: Try loading the full array with the holidays as soon as the page loads, using document.onload, for exemple.

Comment: You are padding the day but not the month, so you will get a date like "01/1/2019". Also, you're setting the value of *holiday*, but returning *feriado*.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code instead - notice the "$.getJSON(url).then(function (data)) {}" instead of your original code.

As someone commented, it appears your issue is due to you using the response before there is an actual response. as $.getJSON is asynchronous.

```
function verifyHoliday(date){
    var url = "https://api.calendario.com.br/?json=true&ano=2018&estado=SP&cidade=MOGI_GUACU&token=ZGdvLmRpZWdvY2FydmFsaG9AZ21haWwuY29tJmhhc2g9MTYzMjcxMDY3";
    var day = (date.getDate() < 10) ? "0"+date.getDate() : date.getDate();
    var dateString = day + "/" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + date.getFullYear();

    //====================================================
    var holiday = false;
    var holidays = [];
    $.getJSON(url).then(function (data) {
      for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        var obj = {day: data[i].date, name: data[i].name};
        holidays[i] = obj;
      }
    });

    for(var i = 0; i < holidays.length; i++){
      if(holidays[i].day == dateString){
          holiday = true;
          break;
      }
    }
    return feriado;
  }
```

Comment: It still returned false...I tried a date that is a holiday here (October 12th) and it returned false.

Comment: This should throw a reference error: `can't find feriado`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code:

1. The call is asynchronous and you aren't waiting for the response
2. You're formatting dates as DD/M/YYYY, so the comparison will fail for single digit months
3. You haven't declared or initialised *feriado* so you should get a reference error

Here's a quick example testing if new year's day is a holiday:

```js
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.onload = function(e) {
  var text = req.response;
  var data = JSON.parse(text);
  var holidays = data.map(hol => ({day:hol.date, name:hol.name}));
  var nyd = '01/01/2018';
  console.log(`Is ${nyd} a holiday? ${holidays.some(hol => hol.day == nyd)}`);
}

var url = 'https://api.calendario.com.br/?json=true&ano=2018&estado=SP&cidade=MOGI_GUACU&token=ZGdvLmRpZWdvY2FydmFsaG9AZ21haWwuY29tJmhhc2g9MTYzMjcxMDY3'
req.open('GET', url); // async request
req.responseType = 'text';
req.send();
```

#### PS

You should only do the request once and store the result as running it on every call to *verifyHoliday* is very inefficient. It's likely that holidays don't change very often (they're usually gazetted years in advance) so even once per day is more than enough.